# Wrong std::vector constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I'm getting a strange error from Clang when compiling what should be a straightforward line of code.

This code produces an error:

```
size_t s = 5;
std::vector<double> bestScores{s, -1.0};
```

I'm simply trying to use [constructor #2](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/) to fill a new vector with five -1.0 values. The error I get is *Non-constant expression cannot be narrowed from type 'size_type' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'double' in initializer list*.

What is going on? This compiles fine:

```
std::vector<double> bestScores{5, -1.0};
```

Is it trying to use the initializer list constructor? I thought you needed two curly braces for that:

```
std::vector<double> bestScores{{5, -1.0}};
```

Comment: You do not need two curly braces for the initializer list constructor, except for `std::array` for confusing and archaic reasons.

Comment: @MooingDuck That must have been what I was thinking of. Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you should read [C++11 - Uniform initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Uniform_initialization), particularly the last two paragraphs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue is that you are constructing the vector using a brace-enclosed initialization list. That favours the `std::initializer_list<T>` constructor when applicable. In this case, the `size_t`, `-1.0` list is compatible with `std::initializer_list<double>`, so that constructor gets picked. You need to use the old-style, C++03 construction:

```
std::vector<double> bestScores(s, -1.0);
```

This is one of the gotchas of brace-enclosed initializers. They don't play well for certain standard library container instantiations. You have to remember that the `std::initializer_list` constructor will trump the others.

Comment: Why would it think `size_t` and `double` are compatible while selecting the constructor, and then throwing the compile-time "narrowing conversion" error later in the process? Does C++ have a non-self-consistency bug or is it a quirk because of their strict backwards compatibility?

Answer (score 6):

The issue is that when a class has an `std::initializer_list` constructor, it will prefer that when using the uniform initialization syntax if the arguments are convertible to the initializer_list's type (`double` in this case).  See a detailed answer at  [programmers.stackexchange.com](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/133688/is-c11-uniform-initialization-a-replacement-for-the-old-style-syntax).

For now, your solution is to use the non-uniform syntax that uses parenthesis.  This means it won't consider the `std::initializer_list` constructor, and do what you want in this case.

`std::vector<double> bestScores(s, -1.0)`